# Jewish Communities in Egypt

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt

Why are there Jewish communities in Egypt when the Torah says never to go back to Egypt? How is this acceptable?

Comment: Ask Yirmeyahu. He went there.

Comment: @Aaron Do you know what he'd say? This isn't a name game to prove great Jews lived there. It's trying to understand how they did.

Comment: @DoubleAA He fled there after the fall of Judah, and many Jews have lived in Egypt for reasons of safety or feeling of persecution. i think when faced with the idea of death in Israel, or safety in Egypt, many (even the most faithful) would take the latter

Comment: @Aaron So you think it was forbidden to go, just Pikuach Nefesh allowed them to? That's quite a novel position. Why didn't they get out as soon as possible?